# Best way to reduce data to its symmetric and antisymmetric components

Tags: fft

I have some noisy data that looks like this:
[image]

I want to find the components that are symmetric and antisymmetric with respect to magnetic field. The first thing I tried was just using:

Symmetric part $= \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[y(x) + y(-x)\right]$

Antisymmetric part $= \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[y(x) - y(-x)\right]$

Which gives this:
[image]

This isn't totally horrible since I was expecting the antisymmetric part to be linear with approximately this slope.

My question: Is there a better way to do this, possibly by using an FFT to break this into sine and cosine components?

(Edit: Fixed math)

Comment: The result will be the same, no matter how you extract symmetric and antisymmetric parts. The decomposition $f(x) = f_-(x) + f_+(x)$ with $f_-(-x)=-f_-(x)$ and $f_+(-x)=f_+(x)$ is unique. However you're missing a factor of $1/2$ in your decomposition. From above it follows that $f_+(x) = (f(x) + f(-x))/2$ and $ f_-(x) = (f(x)-f(-x))/2$

Comment: I was thinking that an FFT method might be more resilient to the noise or something (I know very little about signal processing techniques). (Also, I fixed the factor of 2)

Comment: Well, it depends if you plan on doing anything more than just splitting by symmetry in the frequency domain. Of course, if you want to perform some kind of spectral processing or noise reduction then a frequency domain method might be useful. But just for extracting the odd/even parts it's overkill.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I still think my way seems crude: for each $x_i$ look for the $x_j$ with value closest to $-x_i$ and then symmeterize using $y(x_i)$ and $y(x_j)$. Is there a better time domain method than this sort of 'point by point' algorithm?